# How to synchronize 2 SVN repo as a user?

Tags: svn, diff, commit, synchronize, repository

I have 2 SVN repositories in 2 different networks (they don't see each other). Repo 1 is the main one, development happens here. Repo 2 is mostly static, should almost never be modified, and should basically just mirror the first one.

How could I script the following actions (from a computer with access to both repositories):
-*find the diff* between repo1 and repo2
-*commit those diffs* to repo2.

(Some developers) --> Repo 1 <--- Middle Computer ---> Repo 2 <--- (Mostly check out)

It should be possible to create a new repo from scratch in Repo 2 Location.
Merges from repo2 to repo1 are rare enough that I think I can handle them manually. Something that could merge in both directions would be perfect though.
(even hints about how to do it would be greatly appreciated)

Note: The two repositories have **TOTALLY DIFFERENT REVISION ID**. The repo locations on both servers are slightly different too.

Edit: Bonus point if the solution doesn't require admin rights..

Comment: Please, give more details: does this 2 repos are unrelated (use different UUIDs)? Does you want bidirectional sync? Does you want 1:1 mirroring (N revision from Repo1 must appear as N revisions in Repo 2 with identical log-comments) or it can be "combined" revision?

Comment: @LazyBadger
The problem is that instead of cloning the repo, they were created by raw copy/paste, so they have different IDs..
I only need a master/slave relation, the closest thing I could find is _svnsync_, but it requires to delete and recreate the 2nd repo, and I'm kind of reluctant to do that since it's the only one with the older commit history.